# How to ensure library calls execute in order they are called

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, mutex, imagej

```
    WindowManager.setCurrentWindow(a.getWindow());
    System.err.println("Current window is " + WindowManager.getCurrentWindow());
    WindowManager.setCurrentWindow(b.getWindow());
    System.err.println("Current window is " + WindowManager.getCurrentWindow());
```

WindowManager is a class defined in the ij package [ImageJ's java API - https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/WindowManager.html#setCurrentWindow--], both methods called here are static methods in the WindowManager class, my program is only written in one thread.

The code above varies between printing 'a' 'a' and 'a' 'b'. My assumption here is that WindowManager.setCurrentWindow(ImageWindow x) must be executing in another thread, and it returns control to my thread before it has finished.

Is there a way to ensure the current thread won't continue until the first method has finished it's execution? -- I think I could use a while loop, but I was hoping there would be a more efficient solution than that.

Comment: Not unless the library provides one (which it doesn't seem to).

Comment: As you can see in [the source code](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/source/ij/WindowManager.java), there is no multi-threading and no magic involved. There’s simply a `private static` field `currentWindow` that will be directly written in `setCurrentWindow` and unconditionally returned in `getCurrentWindow()`. If that doesn’t provide the expected results, you should check *your* code, i.e. what `a.getWindow()` and `b.getWindow()` really return or how you determine that you got “'a' 'a'” instead of  “'a' 'b'”. According to your code snippet you’ll see whatever the window’s `toString()` method returns